# Fetching user profile in Bot with MS Teams channel using node sdk v4

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working with Microsoft Bot Framework SDK v3, as well as v4, for node.js. I have one v3 bot & one v4 bot, both with MS teams channel, but I'm not able to get users' profile details in bot code for v4 bot. (exactly looking for [userprincipalname](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-userprincipalname) )

In v3 I'm using TeamsChatConnector which has fetchMembers() which fetches users details, but things have changed in v4. It is also known as 'Fetching the team roster'.
Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#nodejstypescript-example)

In the v4 bot, there is BotFrameworkAdapter which is not specific to MS teams or any other channel. If I inspect activity object, I can see from the 'from' property, it only has user's name:'lastName,First name' AND 
AAD object id, but not userprincipalname which is usually an email address.

How can I get access to users email address or userprincipalname in v4 BOT code if users is using MS teams channel?

```
  connector.fetchMembers(
    (<builder.IChatConnectorAddress>session.message.address).serviceUrl,
    conversationId,
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        session.endDialog('There is some error');
      }
      else {
        session.endDialog('%s', JSON.stringify(result));
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: Did anyone get a chance to look for possible options for this ?

Comment: v3 to v4 is not as easy as it looks. I'm looking at it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here if somebody is as lost as me. You can make a request to the REST API, getting that information. [Here you can see the endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#rest-api-example)

And here you can see how to set up the headers: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Combining both, making a GET will return context of the users in a team chat or 1:1 chat.